# android Card IO? Error at BuildConfig

Tags: android, ocr, capture

I want to Capture Credit card as a Image And send them to server.

Here I followed [CardIO](https://www.card.io/) to capture Credit card

Here I Used [this](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source) sample code

So here I am getting these errors..
in `CardIOActivity.java`

at `return BuildConfig.PRODUCT_VERSION;`

Error cannot resolve `BuildConfig` in CardIOActivity.java
Even after cleaning also I am getting same error...

Is there is any other way to capture of this kind..

I am getting this at build gradle..

[image]

Comment: what about merge another image above your card  ?

Comment: gradle sync and Try to click on synchronize, on the right side of save may help you

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/08/merge-two-image-overlap-with-alpha.html